# Csc/ CoreCompile fails for PCL/ Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, akavache

my Xamarin app doesn't build anymore since I added Akavache to it.
Csc/ CoreCompile fails. If I remove Akavache, It builds fine. There aren't any errors, but I could find the following error in the output window:

```
8>  Output Item(s): CscCommandLineArgs= (TaskId:201)
8>Done executing task "Csc" -- FAILED. (TaskId:201)
8>Done building target "CoreCompile" in project "My.App.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:242)
8>Target "_CheckForCompileOutputs: (TargetId:243)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets" from project "C:\git\Apps\My.App\My.App.csproj" (target "_CleanGetCurrentAndPriorFileWrites" depends on it):
8>Set Property: _DocumentationFileProduced=false
8>Set Property: _DebugSymbolsProduced=false
8>Done building target "_CheckForCompileOutputs" in project "My.App.csproj".: (TargetId:243)
```

I'm using Akavache 5.0 in a PCL-project for Xamarin. Only my app's PCL project fails to build. But Akavache is used in another/ a referenced PCL-project called My.App.Data. The target frameworks are Xamarin standards: .NET framework 4.5, ASP.NET Core 1.0, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS (Classic) and Xamarin.Mac.

The build fails as soon as Akavache is used by "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe":

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:C:\git\App\Packages\akavache.core.5.0.0\lib\Portable-Net45+Win8+WP8+Wpa81\Akavache.dll /reference:C:\git\App\Packages\akavache.sqlite3.5.0.0\lib\Portable-Net45+Win8+WP8+Wpa81\Akavache.Sqlite3.dll ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue. I used Splat in version 2.0 instead of 1.6.